# linux distro for ase sybase?

Tags: sybase, vagrant, sap-ase

I am currently configuring a vm on using vagrant and need to set up ase sybase. I have had no luck with ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS as the glibc are not compatible.

The available vm linux distros that I have available are listed on this url:

```
http://www.vagrantbox.es/
```

there is no red-hat distro, but a scientific linux 6 distro.

Could someone tell me out of the list what my best chances of getting ase sybase to run.

The version of ase sybase I am trying to use is found here :

http://www.sybase.com/linux

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is the free version of Red Hat, so I would suggest trying that.

Answer (score 0):

In January 2011, I managed to install and use Sybase ASE on Fedora 14.
You could try the distro Fedora 17. Let us know if it works.

Comment: I will get back to you when I have given it ago :-D

Comment: Did you manage to install it on Linux? If yes, which distribution?